# Identify which encoding PayPal IPN uses?

Tags: c#, encoding, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am having some issues with **PayPal IPN**. The documentation uses **ASCII** encoding. I am using **UTF-8**. It works fine but as a rarest case I get some random characters. As far as I know the Paypal account can be setup for different encoding. Is there any way to identify that?.

Or is there a standard way of handling all the cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this as a part of the solution.

specifying the encoding method used in the form we send to paypal

```
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">
```

This [link](https://cms.paypal.com/es/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_formbasics) is more helpful

Comment: Setting this has no effect on IPN encoding. See below (@Robert's answer).

Answer (score 12):

You can set the encoding for IPN via Account Settings > Website Payments > PayPal Button Language Encoding > More Options.
([direct link](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-language-encoding))

The IPN message itself contains a 'charset' field as well which you can check against. See also https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro#id091F0M006Y4

Comment: That's true I agree with that, but what if my IPN listener does not know about that encoding?

Comment: The IPN message itself contains a 'charset' field as well which you can check against. See also: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro#id091F0M006Y4

Comment: Thanks Robert that helps. I just wonder if it will overwrite the setting made on the profile and is it a good practice

Comment: That value should show the setting from the Profile, since there is no other way to set/override the IPN charset.

Comment: @Robert I think you should add your first comment to the answer as it is much more scalable (e.g. if you have many customers that you are implementing IPN for, asking each of them to set encoding via their profiles is not feasible, but checking/converting against an already existing value can be done automatically). Also a great catch.

Comment: it seems "charset" is no longer included in the ipn message?

Comment: Why on the world wouldn't PayPal default to UTF-8 encoding. Some engineers just want to watch the world burn.

Comment: @Mahn PayPal's IPN system dates back to the 1990s before knowledge of internationalization was widespread amongst web-developers - they can't risk breaking hundreds of thousands of websites. FWIW, PayPal has a set of new web-APIs (such as their new Webhook API) which look like they'll replace IPN in the long-term.